# How to remove substring from the cell in google sheets via script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automate the process of parsing data in one of my columns. So far I have it so that after applying a formula I get the data I need but with text around it.
I would like to find and replace the cell values such that I only have the data that is in quotations marks without the quotations. How would I do this via script? Refer to the picture below. This is what I have so far:

```
var src = ":utm_source=>";
  var med = ":utm_medium=>";
  var camp = ":utm_campaign=>";
  var term = ":utm_term=>";
  var con = ":utm_content=>";
  var r1 = "";
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(data.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length;i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length;j++){
      Logger.log(data[j][i]);
      if(data[j][i].indexOf(src) > -1 || data[j][i].indexOf(med) > -1 || data[j][i].indexOf(camp) > -1 || data[j][i].indexOf(term) > -1 || data[j][i].indexOf(con) > -1){
      sheet.getRange(j+1,i+1).setValue(r1);
        sheet
      }
    }
  }
```

[image: picture of data and desired result]

Comment: Welcome to [so].  What is the problem with the script you included? Also please add a [mcve].

Comment: try splitting on " and take the second term

Comment: @Cooper how would I go about doing that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Hi, I would use a spreadsheet formula for this, much faster than Apps script, try this function, asuming the data to parse is in B16  :  =mid(B16,find("""",B16)+1,find("""",B16,find("""",B16)+1)-(find("""",B16)+1))

Answer (score 0):

- Use `split('"')[1]` (see [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) to retrieve the substring between the quotations.
- As a [best practice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations), modify the 2D array you retrieved (`data`) and use [setValues(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)), instead of setting every individual with `setValue`. One way to do that it through a combination of [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), as can be seen below (check inline comments):

```
var src = ":utm_source=>";
var med = ":utm_medium=>";
var camp = ":utm_campaign=>";
var term = ":utm_term=>";
var con = ":utm_content=>";
var starters = [src,med,camp,term,con]; // Put all starters to check in an array
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = range.getValues();
data = data.map(row => row.map(value => { // Iterate through all rows and cells
  var includesStarter = starters.some(starter => value.includes(starter)); // Check if cell value includes a starter
  if (includesStarter) return value.split('"')[1]; // Retrieve value within quotations
  else return value; // If starter is not included in cell, don't change the array
}));
range.setValues(data); // Write modified data to original range
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering. I figured it out yesterday. I used an array to store the strings and used a foreach loop to make the replacements. Thank you though. I appreciate it.

Comment: @MuzammilElahi Are you replacing each value separately via `setValue`, or replacing all at once with `setValues`? If you're using `setValue`, I recommend to use `setValues` instead for efficiency purposes (see the code snippet in my answer) (read [Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)).